# What section I would be in (13yo, D#2 - A5, E6)?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I can hit a D#2. I am 13. I am kind of confused on what section I would be (i.e. bass, baritone etc.) I can go up to an A5 note with my chest voice. In my head voice I can hit a E6 comfortably. Can someone please explain what section I should be in?

Comment: Your voice will most likely change - a lot - in the next few years. If you're interested in order to join a choir, then abide by the choirmaster's decision - for now. Otherwise, any answer will be about right for maybe a few months.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a common reference chart of vocal ranges, but keep in mind that what matters is not simply the absolute lowest and highest notes you can hit, what really matters is the range you can use effortlessly and without straining.

Additionally, being 13, expect that range and other characteristics of your voice are going to keep changing, sometimes slowly and sometimes suddenly, over the next few years.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_range#Vocal_range_and_voice_classification

Comment: I have already hit puberty and I am in a choir but the director won't put me in a specific section.

Comment: I can't speak for the director's choices, but perhaps you can take this as a unique opportunity to gain experience doing a wider variety of parts and see how your still evolving voice handles all that. And by the way, it's not just puberty itself, but the still growing body, developing muscles, changes in proportions and shapes -- your voice will go on evolving for at least another 10 years before settling into a somewhat stable form.

Comment: Do you know that song that is in frozen 2? "Into the unknown"? I can hit all of those notes on 3 different octaves. My choir instructor is making me kind of nervous by not giving me a specific section. I don't know if that makes sense to anyone but yeah.

Comment: If your interest in singing is more than a hobby, never mind what the director says, take things in your own hands and become more aware of the many possibilities in front of you. Have you seen the movie "Maria by Callas"? https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7364566/ especially the parts about her early practice years (around your age too). You can learn a lot from it. Also look for interviews with great singers who talk about their early years, there's much to learn.